# PHP/Javascript: Making (1) in title as unread

Tags: php, javascript

```
$counter = $sWall + $sWC + $sOther;
if (!empty($counter)) {
    echo '(' . $counter . ')';
    $counter = 0;
}
```

And js:

```
    $(window).blur(function() {
        tracktime = new Date();
         setInterval(function() { 
      $.ajax({ 
       type: "POST",
       url: "imback.php",
    data: {
    mode: 'ajax',
            getUpdates: 'auto',
            },
       success: function(msg){
       document.title = msg + document.title;
    }
     });
}, 2000);

    })
```

For showing new unread comments in the title bar. Works fine and displays it as (1), although everytime it call, it adds a (1) so the title gets like this: (1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(1).......

And i only want it to do it once (1) no matter how many calls, so if a new call is response is (2) then it will show (2) and not (2)(1)(1)....

How can i fix this the best way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var initial_title = document.title;
    $(window).blur(function() {
        tracktime = new Date();
        setInterval(function() { 
            $.ajax({ 
                type: "POST",
                url: "imback.php",
                data: {
                    mode: 'ajax',
                    getUpdates: 'auto',
                },
               success: function(msg){
                    document.title = msg + initial_title;
               }
           });
        }, 2000);
    });

    $(window).focus(function () { document.title = initial_title; });
})();
```

Comment: Works although remove the () at last

Comment: @user457827 the `()` is there with a purpose; I wrapped the script in a self-executing anonymous function, so that it doesn't pollute the global namespace with the `initial_title` variable. You could remove the wrapping function if you wanted, but I put it there because I wanted it to be as "clean" as possible

Comment: I get firebug error on all my other js stuff i have when i have it.

Comment: hmm, interesting. Check if it works without the wrapper function (just remove the first and last line)

Comment: You probably need to wrap this in an initialization handler.

Answer (score 3):

When the page is loaded, save the original title to a variable, then when you need to update it, use the saved value.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to store the original title in a variable and then prepend the `msg` variable to that title variable.

```
var titleOrig = document.title;

$(window).blur(function() {
    tracktime = new Date();
    setInterval(function() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "imback.php",
            data: {
                mode: 'ajax',
                getUpdates: 'auto',
            },
            success: function(msg){
                document.title = msg + titleOrig;
            }
        });
    }, 2000);
})
```

You should wrap this in an init function somewhere, but it's the general idea.